# Change the order and style of HTML attribute output with Emmet?

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext3, emmet

Is there any way that I can alter the output order and style of the attributes when expanding an abbreviation in **Emmet for Sublime Text 3**?

I prefer to have class names as the first attribute on any HTML element, simply so that I don't have to go searching for them when I'm writing my CSS. By default, Emmet expands with the required attributes first where there are multiple attributes to output. Is there any way to make the class attribute show up first wherever it is present?

Secondly, I like my class names double-spaced for clarity. Is it possible to do this too using the abbreviation settings in Emmet?

**Example:**

*Emmet default output*

```
<a href="/donate" class="main-nav__link main-nav__link--accented">Donate</a>
```

*Desired output*

```
<a class="main-nav__link  main-nav__link--accented" href="/donate">Donate</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) :
*Create snippets.json file in extensions folder to add or override snippets.*